# How to pass data from one component to another component in onchange using React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two component 1. Filter and 2.Data

I have injected both components in `main.js` file

1.Main.js

```
render() {
        return (
            <div className={classes.Main}> 
                <Filter />
                <DataComponent />
            </div>
        );
    }
```

2.Filter Component

In the filter, the component has two dropdowns 1. Color and 2.class 
based on the dropdown selection need to pass the data from filter component to data component

```
import React from 'react'; 

const Filter = (props) => {
    return (
        <div>
          <ul>
            <li className={classes.displayInline} >
              <select name='color' onChange={this.handleChange} > 
                <option value='0'>Select</option>
                <option value='1'>red</option>
                <option value='2'>blue</option>
              </select>
            </li>
            <li className={classes.displayInline} >
              <select name='class' >
                <option value='0'>Select Class</option>
                <option value='1'>first</option>
                <option value='2'>Second</option>
                <option value='3'>Third</option>
                <option value='4'>Fourth</option>
              </select>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Filter;
```

3.Data Component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'; 
class DataComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { 
            items: [],
            content: [],
        }

    } 
    componentDidMount() {
        fetch("url")

            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(
                (result) => {
                    this.setState({
                        isLoaded: true,
                        items: result
                    });
                },
                (error) => {
                    this.setState({
                        isLoaded: true,
                        error
                    });
                }
            )

    } 
    render() {

            /**** data getting from api is pushed to content ****/

            content.push(items);
        });
        return ( 
         /**** render part ***/

        )
    } 
}
export default DataComponent;
```

Need to get the dropdown values from the filter component to data component.

I have new to reactjs framework.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> In Filter Component

```
handleChange = (event) => {
    if(typeof this.props.selectedValueHandler !== 'undefined'){
        this.props.selectedValueHandler(event.target.value);
    }
}
```

> In Main Component

In you main file you need to pass a function `selectedValueHandler` as 
a prop to the filtercomponent, which will be used as a callback filtercomponent
from inside the `Filter` component on selection.

The selected value then can be passed to `Data Componennt`

```
constructor() {
    this.state = {
        selectedValue: null
    }
}

selectedValueHandler = (selectedValue) => {
    this.setState({
        selectedValue
    })
}

render() {
        const { selectedValue } = this.state;
        return (
            <div className={classes.Main}> 
                <Filter selectedValueHandler={this.selectedValueHandler}/>
                <DataComponent selectedValue={selectedValue} />
            </div>
        );
    }
```

> In your Data Component

You can directly access the selected value in Data Component using

```
class DataComponent extends Component {
    render() {
        const { selectedValue } = this.props;
        ...
    }
}
```

or if you want to make it part of Data Component State.

```
class DataComponent extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { 
            items: [],
            content: [],
            selectedValue: this.props.selectedValue
        }
    } 

    componentwillreceiveprops(nextProps) {
        if(this.state.selectedValue !== nextProps.selectedValue) {
            this.setState({
                selectedValue: nextProps.selectedValue
            })
        }

    }

    render() {
        const { selectedValue } = this.state;
        ...
    }
}
```

Depends on your use case.

Comment: @anushul .: thanks, i can get the value from filter to main component. but i cant get the selectedValue in data component. using selectedValue variable i try to get the result in data component in constructor function, is it correct way ?

Comment: @karthick, constructor function is called only once in the lifecycle, it is advised to use it directly in render or use another componentwillrecieveprops to handle. I have updated answer for reference. :)

Comment: Beware of using `componentWillReceiveProps` as it is a deprecated function. To future-proof you should consider alternative design.

Answer (score 4):

According to my knowledge, there are 2 way for solving this problem:

1. Using Redux for controlling the common state of your application. Please see an example in Redux website (https://redux.js.org/basics/exampletodolist)
2. Using parent's state

**In your Main.js** init the state for containing the change in its child **Filter**

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { 
        value: null, //used to contains your dropdown value
    }
    this.getDropdownData = this.getDropdownData.bind(this);
}
```

and the function for getting the value from Filter

```
getDropdownData(value){
    this.setState({
        value : myvalue
    });
}
```

then pass the `getDropdownData()` function to getting data to **Filter** and the `value` in state to **Data Component**

```
render() {
        return (
            <div className={classes.Main}> 
                <Filter getDropdownData = {this.getDropdownData}/>
                <DataComponent dropdownValue = {this.state.value}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
```

**In Filter.js**

Call the passed function in `this.handleChange` by using `this.props.getDropdownData(input_dropdown_value)`

Do not forget to bind `this.handleChange` in the `constructor()`

```
this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
```

**Finally**

Using the drop-down value in **DataComponent** by calling `this.props.dropdownValue`

Hope it can help you

Answer (score 1):

My first instinct is to say that you should simply combine the two components into one.

Components have the ability to carry state for a reason. There's not much point using a functional component and then splitting it's state into a separate component.

Having `content.push` in your `render` function also is a bit weird to do for React. Your `render` function should be solely responsible for rendering, nothing else. If you want to do something in your `render` function, make a handler.

Here's how I'd build your filter class, bear in mind this code is written without being tested so it may require some tweaks, but the general structure is all there.

```
import React from 'react'

export default class Filter extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      items: [],
      content: [],
      isLoaded: false,
      error: null,
      selectedColorFilter: null,
      selectedClassFilter: null
    }

    //There's probably a better way to refactor this so it's just one handler, but I'm just using two for illustrative purposes here.
    this.handleColorFilterChange = this.handleColorFilterChange.bind(this)
    this.handleClassFilterChange = this.handleClassFilterChange.bind(this)
  }

  componentDidMount () {
    fetch('url')
      .then((res) => {
        return res.json()
      })
      .then((data) => {
        this.setState({
          isLoaded: true,
          items: data
        })
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        this.setState({
          isLoaded: false,
          error: error
        })
      })
  }

  handleColorFilterChange (event) {
    //this may not be right, but I think it'll pick up the right value, may have to change it
    this.state.selectedColorFilter = event.target.value
  }

  handleClassFilterChange (event) {
    //again, might not be right, but I think it'll grab the value
    this.state.selectedClassFilter = event.target.value
  }

  renderColorFilter () {
    <li className={classes.displayInline} >
      <select name='color' onChange={this.handleColorFilterChange} > 
        <option value='0'>Select</option>
        <option value='1'>red</option>
        <option value='2'>blue</option>
      </select>
    </li>
  }

  renderClassFilter () {
    <li className={classes.displayInline} >
      <select name='class' onChange={this.handleClassFilterChange} >
        <option value='0'>Select Class</option>
        <option value='1'>first</option>
        <option value='2'>Second</option>
        <option value='3'>Third</option>
        <option value='4'>Fourth</option>
      </select>
    </li>
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <ul>
          {this.renderColorFilter()}
          {this.renderClassFilter()}
        </ul>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Hope this makes sense.