# Dropdown Value not passing from one component to the other - React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to create a web-app with the front end in React and backend in Flask. I have a dropdown which gets populated by the flask JSON which is basically a list of companies. All total there are around 5 components, the first one is the **App.js**, second is the **CompanySelection.js**, the third one is the **Chart.js** where I want to return my graphs and all.

So in the**CompanySelection.js** when I change the dropdown selection the updated company name does not go into **Charts.js**, i.e. the other component. I guess when this part gets solved similarly I can pass the values from one component to the other easily.

These are my three code files:

**App.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { CompanyContextProvider } from "./context";
import Dropdown from 'react-dropdown';
import 'react-dropdown/style.css';
import Header from "./Header";
import CompanySelection from "./CompanySelection/CompanySelection.js";
import Charts from "./Charts/Chart.js";
import axios from 'axios';

class App extends React.Component{

    state = {
                companies: [],
                firstCompany: {},
                firstCompanyName: ''
            };


  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('http://127.0.0.1:5001/algo/loc')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
    this.setState({companies: data,
                    firstCompany: data[0],
                    firstCompanyName: data[0].value}, () => 
    console.log(this.state.companies, this.state.firstCompany, this.state.firstCompanyName));
    console.log('')

  }).catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
  }

  selectedValueHandler = (selectedValue) => {
    this.setState({
        firstCompanyName: selectedValue
    })
}

  render() {
    const { selectedValue } = this.state.firstCompanyName;
    console.log('change value',selectedValue)
    return (
        <div className="app">
          <Header/> 
          <CompanySelection companies= {this.state.companies} selectedCompany={this.state.firstCompany} setSelectedCompany={this.state.firstCompanyName} selectedValueHandler = {this.selectedValueHandler}/>
          <Charts companies= {this.state.companies} selectedCompany={this.state.firstCompany} setSelectedCompany={selectedValue}/>

        </div>
        );
  }
} ;

export default App;
```

**CompanySelection.js**

```
import { h, render, Component} from 'preact';
import style from './style.css';
import { useContext } from "preact/hooks";
import { CompanyContext } from "../context";

class CompanySelection extends Component {

    constructor(props) 
    { 
        super(props); 
    } 

  render(_, { value }) {

    const companies = this.props.companies;
    const selectedCompany = this.props.selectedCompany; 
    const setSelectedCompany = this.props.setSelectedCompany; 

    var onChange = (e) =>{
        console.log("In on change");
        this.setState({ value: e.target.value });
        const setSelectedCompany = e.target.value;
        console.log("Selected", e.target.value);
        const companies = this.props.companies;
        const selectedCompany = this.props.selectedCompany; 
        this.props.selectedValueHandler(e.target.value);
    }


    if (typeof companies !== 'undefined')
    {
        var options = companies.map((comp) =>
                    <option 
                        key={comp.label}
                        value={comp.value}
                    >
                        {comp.label}
                    </option>
                );
    }
    else {
        var options = [{value: 'A', label: 'B'}].map((comp) =>
                    <option 
                        key={comp.label}
                        value={comp.value}
                    >
                        {comp.label}
                    </option>
                );
    }
    return (
        <fragment class={style.fragment}>
        <label class={style.label}> Company </label>
        <select value={value} onChange={onChange} class={style.dropdown}>
        {options}
        </select>
        </fragment>
    );

  }
}

render(<CompanySelection />, document.body);
export default CompanySelection;
```

**Chart.js**

```
import {  h, render, Component } from 'preact';
import style from './style.css';
import { VictoryChart, VictoryLine, VictoryScatter, VictoryLabel} from 'victory';
import { useContext } from "preact/hooks";
import { CompanyContext } from "../context";

class Charts extends Component {

    constructor(props) 
    { 
        super(props); 
    } 

  render(_, { value }) {
    const companies = this.props.companies;
    const selectedCompany = this.props.selectedCompany; 
    const setSelectedCompany = this.props.setSelectedCompany;
    console.log('list of companies chart', companies)
    console.log('chart input', setSelectedCompany)
    if (typeof selectedCompany !== 'undefined') {
        var comp = selectedCompany;
    }
    else {
        var comp = '';
    }
    console.log("comp", comp);
    return (
        <fragment>
            <div class={style.chart}>
                <VictoryChart domain={[0, 10]}>
                  <VictoryLabel text={comp} x={225} y={30} textAnchor="middle"/>
                  <VictoryLine
                    style={{ data: { stroke: "blue", strokeWidth: 3 } }}
                    y={(d) => d.x}
                  />
                  <VictoryScatter
                    symbol="star"
                    size={8}
                    style={{ data: { fill: "red" }}}
                    data={[{ x: 5, y: 5 }]}
                  />
                  <VictoryScatter
                    symbol="circle"
                    size={8}
                    style={{ data: { fill: "red" }}}
                    data={[{ x: 7, y: 7 }]}
                  />
                </VictoryChart>
            </div>
        </fragment>
    );
  }
}

render(<Charts />, document.body);
export default Charts;
```

I have taken reference of this code from this stackoverflow post: [How to pass data from one component to another component in onchange using React js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51999538/how-to-pass-data-from-one-component-to-another-component-in-onchange-using-react)

However when I see the output of this line of code: `const { selectedValue } = this.state.firstCompanyName;
        console.log('change value',selectedValue)`

I get that change value undefined, which means the values are not getting passed on. I'm very new to react and haven't been able to solve this yet. Any help is much appreciated.

P.S. The components pass on well to the `<CompanySelection..../>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`However when I see the output of this line of code: const { selectedValue } = this.state.firstCompanyName;
        console.log('change value',selectedValue)`

It will be undefined, here you are trying to destructure selectedValue from a string firstCompanyName, as long as `this.state.firstCompanyName` is not an object with a key named `selectedValue` it will be undefined.  Instead do this.

```
    const  selectedValue = this.state.firstCompanyName;
    console.log('change value',selectedValue)`
```