# React Component keeps on Rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have three files **App.js**, **CompanySelection.js** and **Chart.js**. the `CompanySelection` component has a dropdown (list of company names) from where I'm getting the values and want to pass it into the `Chart` component to plot some graph.

However I have a flask component to be called, here are the codes of the two files:

**App.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { CompanyContextProvider } from "./context";
import Dropdown from 'react-dropdown';
import 'react-dropdown/style.css';
import Header from "./Header";
import CompanySelection from "./CompanySelection/CompanySelection.js";
import Charts from "./Charts/Chart.js";
import axios from 'axios';

class App extends React.Component{

    state = {
                companies: [],
                firstCompany: {},
                firstCompanyName: ''
            };


  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('http://127.0.0.1:5001/algo/loc')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
    this.setState({companies: data,
                    firstCompany: data[0],
                    firstCompanyName: data[0].value}, () => 
    console.log(this.state.companies, this.state.firstCompany, this.state.firstCompanyName));
    console.log('')

  }).catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
  }

  selectedValueHandler = (selectedValue) => {
    this.setState({
        firstCompanyName: selectedValue
    })
}

  render() {
    const  selectedValue  = this.state.firstCompanyName;
    console.log('change value',selectedValue)
    return (
        <div className="app">
          <Header/> 
          <CompanySelection companies= {this.state.companies} selectedCompany={this.state.firstCompany} setSelectedCompany={this.state.firstCompanyName} selectedValueHandler = {this.selectedValueHandler}/>
          <Charts companies= {this.state.companies} selectedCompany={this.state.firstCompany} setSelectedCompany={selectedValue}/>

        </div>
        );
  }
} ;

export default App;
```

**Chart.js**

```
import {  h, render, Component } from 'preact';
import style from './style.css';
import { VictoryChart, VictoryLine, VictoryScatter, VictoryLabel} from 'victory';
import { useContext } from "preact/hooks";
import { CompanyContext } from "../context";

class Charts extends Component {

    constructor(props) 
    { 
        super(props); 
    } 

    state = {
                anomalies: [],
                dates: [],
                currentcomp: ''
            };


  render(_, { value }) {

    const companies = this.props.companies;
    const selectedCompany = this.props.selectedCompany; 
    const setSelectedCompany = this.props.setSelectedCompany;
    console.log('list of companies chart', companies)
    console.log('chart input', setSelectedCompany)

    const start_date = "2017-01-01"
    const end_date = "2020-01-01"

    const url = 'http://127.0.0.1:5001/algo/anom_score/'+setSelectedCompany+','+start_date+','+end_date

    fetch(url)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
    this.setState({anomalies: data,
                   dates: data['Anomaly Date']}, () => 
    console.log('Anomalies',this.state.anomalies));

  }).catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });

    if (typeof setSelectedCompany !== 'undefined') {
        var comp = setSelectedCompany;
    }
    else {
        var comp = '';
    }
    console.log("comp", comp);
    return (
        <fragment>
            <div class={style.chart}>
            <div className="content" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: this.state.anomalies}}></div>
                <VictoryChart domain={[0, 10]}>
                  <VictoryLabel text={comp} x={225} y={30} textAnchor="middle"/>
                  <VictoryLine
                    style={{ data: { stroke: "blue", strokeWidth: 3 } }}
                    y={(d) => d.x}
                  />
                  <VictoryScatter
                    symbol="star"
                    size={8}
                    style={{ data: { fill: "red" }}}
                    data={[{ x: 5, y: 5 }]}
                  />
                  <VictoryScatter
                    symbol="circle"
                    size={8}
                    style={{ data: { fill: "red" }}}
                    data={[{ x: 7, y: 7 }]}
                  />
                </VictoryChart>
            </div>
        </fragment>
    );
  }
}

render(<Charts />, document.body);
export default Charts;
```

I have tried placing the following code lines:

```
const companies = this.props.companies;
const selectedCompany = this.props.selectedCompany; 
const setSelectedCompany = this.props.setSelectedCompany;
console.log('list of companies chart', companies)
console.log('chart input', setSelectedCompany)
```

inside `componentDidMount()` and tried to fetch the values but it is not able to retrieve the values and that `fetch(url)` never gets triggered.

However placing the same thing insider the `render(_,{value})` function seems to be working pretty well. But the component keeps on rendering (infinitely) and as a result changing the dropdown value makes the API calls very slow from flask.

I am very new to React JS so not able to understand whether its a conceptual mistake that I am making? Or how can I stop the re-rendering?

I have tried multiple solutions but nothing seemed to work/

P.S. This post can be considered as a continuation of this one: [Dropdown Value not passing from one component to the other - React JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61074668/dropdown-value-not-passing-from-one-component-to-the-other-react-js), you can refer to this post in case `CompanyContext.js` code is required

Comment: Hi. You should not be using fetch or any side effect causing code, or setState within render method. calling setState will cause a component to re-render, and while re-rendering you are calling setState again, and that causes infinite loop. Move that fetch related code to componentDidMount of Charts component. It should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to place the code in `componendDidUpdate` since when you change your state in `App.js`, your componentDidUpdate fires every time.

```
fetchData(){
 const companies = this.props.companies;
    const selectedCompany = this.props.selectedCompany; 
    const setSelectedCompany = this.props.setSelectedCompany;
    console.log('list of companies chart', companies)
    console.log('chart input', setSelectedCompany)

    // fetch(URL) AND SET STATE
      ........

}

componentDidMount(){
  this.fetchData(); // INITIAL FETCH
}

componentDidUpdate(prevProps){
  if(prevProps.selectedCompany !== this.props.selectedCompany){
    this.fetchData();  // FETCH WHEN PROPS CHANGE
  }
}
```

Comment: it says `fetchData` is not defined inside `componentDidMount` function, why is it so? and moreover the change occurs in the `CompanySelection.js` like I have mentioned, but that shouldn't be a problem i guess

Comment: `this.fetchData()` worked. Have edited your answer. Works though. Thanks!

Comment: @DebadriDutta Yes it would be `this.fetchData()`, thanks for edit, and don't forget to mark it as answer if it was what you were looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

you are calling the api inside the render function and setting some state. it will make a infinite loop

1) first the render method calls

2) it hits the asi and set the state

3) as state is changed it again re-render and set the state

4) and the loop goes continously

try to make the api hit in the componentDidMOunt()