# Nested JSON to HTML Tables - React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am returning a nested JSON from my Flask response to React. You can refer to the architecture of the Flask API hit and all from the code here: [React Component keeps on Rendering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61084388/react-component-keeps-on-rendering)

And now I have a nested kind of JSON in my React, where the data looks something like this:

On printing `this.state.scores` from `this.setState({scores: data})` (Here data comes from `fetchurl(127.0.0.1)`, the flask API), the JSON Output:

```
{
all_scores: "{
             "Dates":{"0":"2019-01-01","1":"2019-01-02","2":"2019-01-03"},
             "Start Score":{"0":"708","1":"227","2":"362"},
             "End Score":{"0":"800","1":"600","2":"600"}
             }"

all_text: "{
            "Dates":{"0":"2019-01-01","1":"2019-01-02","2":"2019-01-03"},
            "Name":{"0":"Bill","1":"Joe","2":"Harry"},
            "Description":{"0":"Bill played excellently...", "1":"Missing", "2":"Harry did wonders. His innings..."}
           }"

all_numeric:"{
              "Dates": {"0":"2019-01-01","1":"2019-01-02","2":"2019-01-01"}, 
              "Loss":{"0":"200","1":"300","2":"400"},
              "Extras":{"0":"2","1":"3","2":"10"}
              }"
}
```

**Update**:
The current format of the data looks like this for `all_scores` and others:

```
[
    {
        "Dates":"2019-01-01",
        "Start_Score":"708",
        "End Score":"800"
    },
    {
        "Dates":"2019-01-02",
        "Start_Score":"227",
        "End Score":"600"
    },
    {
        "Dates":"2019-01-01",
        "Start_Score":"362",
        "End Score":"600"
    }
]
```

Now I want to render each primary key(`all_scores`, `all_text`) of the json as a whole table having the columns and the values as specified under each of them, something like this:

**For `all_scores`**:

```
|Dates       | Start Score | End Score|
---------------------------------------
|2019-01-01  | 708         | 800      |
|2019-01-02  | 227         | 600      |
|2019-01-03  | 362         | 600      |
```

**For `all_text`**:

```
|Dates       | Name | Description                                                                   |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|2019-01-01  | Bill | Bill Played excellently. He played some extra ordinary shots and won the match| 
|2019-01-02  | Joe  | Missing                                                                       |
|2019-01-03  | Harry| His innings was the most crucial one. Results could have been different       |
```

I have been able to access the primary key values like this: `this.state.scores.all_scores` and the other ones as well but not able to convert it to a table.

I am very new to react, have tried multiple solutions, but this problem seemed to be a bit different and hence those solutions did not workout. Any help is appreciated.

The JS File (**Chart.js**), where I want to render the tables:

```
import {  h, render, Component } from 'preact';
import style from './style.css';
import { useContext } from "preact/hooks";

class Charts extends Component {

    constructor(props) 
    { 
        super(props); 
    } 

    state = {
                scores: [],
                currentteam: ''
            };

    fetchData(){
    const teams= this.props.teams;
    const currentteam= this.props.currentteam; 
    const setTeam = this.props.setTeam ;
    this.setState({currentteam:setTeam })
    console.log('list of teams', teams)
    console.log('chart input', setTeam )

    const start_date = "2019-01-01"
    const end_date = "2019-01-10"

    const url = 'http://127.0.0.1:5001/score/'+setTeam +','+start_date+','+end_date

    fetch(url)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
    this.setState({scores: data}, () => 
    console.log('Scores',this.state.scores, 'Team', this.state.currentteam));

  }).catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });

}

  componentDidMount(){
  this.fetchData(); 
}

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps){
  if(prevProps.currentteam!== this.props.setTeam){
    this.fetchData();  
  }
}


  render(_, { value }) {

    console.log('Current Team', this.state.currentteam)
    const scores= this.state.scores
    console.log('Assigning scores to constant', scores)
    return (
        <fragment>

      <div>
        <p> Following are the dates for {this.state.currentteam}:
        <br/>{scores.all_text} // Using this I am able to print df2 as to validate the output
        <br/>
        </p>
      </div>
        </fragment>
    );
  }
}

render(<Charts />, document.body);
export default Charts;
```

P.S. In layman terms this my whole App architecture, three dataframes are converted to json and an emptry dataframe is created with three columns having each of the JSON of the three dataframes. I'm returning this whole dataframe as `jsonify(full_data)` which is being returned to react and this is how my data looks like.

Comment: First, check the flask output api call is returning valid JSON, using something like https://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to loop over your data.
Don`t think how you will implement it with React, it is simple looping, React will just show the data.

For example for `all_text` just start by

- looping all `Object.keys(all_text)` which will give you table
  headings.
- then loop all values for every key ( Date, Name and etc ) and print
  them in the table row

My advice once again - try to accomplish this without React with pure JS and output the results in console. That why you will prevent some React speficic mystakes that you could make

Answer (score 0):

First, you'll need to correct your flask output, so that the three child objects are not in quotes (as they're currently being interpreted as strings), and personally, I would use arrays as the inner object here, as all you have are indexes and values. eg.

```js
{
"all_scores": {
         "Dates":['2019-01-01','2019-01-02','2019-01-03'],
         "Start Score":['708','227','362'],
         "End Score":['800','600','600']
         },
"all_text": {
        "Dates":['2019-01-01','2019-01-02','2019-01-03'],
        "Name":['Bill','Joe','Harry'],
        "Description":['Bill played excellently...', 'Missing', 'Harry did wonders. His innings...']
       },
"all_numeric":{
          "Dates": ['2019-01-01','2019-01-02','2019-01-01'],
          "Loss":['200','300','400'],
          "Extras":['2','3','10']
          }
}
```

Now, you have the objects so you should be able to access and loop over them

Now, this is not quite tested code, but a loop might look like this:

```js
return (
var x =0;
var all_scores = this.state.scores.all_scores;
for (x=0;x<=all_scores.Dates.length;x++) {
   <tr><td>{all_scores.Dates[x]}</td><td>{all_scores."Start Score"[x]}</td><td>{all_scores."End Score"[x]}</td></tr>;
};
)
```

For the updated data structure, you could simply map the output such as:

```js
this.state.scores.all_scores.map(score =>{
  <tr><td>{score.Dates}</td><td>{score.Start_Score}</td><td>{score["End Score"]}</td></tr>;
})
```

Note: you'll need to reference the end score differently, as it has a space in the name, so it can't be found using the . reference.

Comment: an even better arrangement of data so that you could use map easily, would be to have each table object return an array of objects. Eg. all_scores:[{Date:"1/1/1",Start:"1",End:"3"},{Date:"2/1/1", Start:"1",End:"6"}]

Comment: This all assumes that you can change the flask API... if not, then you have some transform / cleanup to do in JS

Comment: Umm, thanks for the suggestions. Do u have any idea how can i return multiple pandas dataframes as a single json object and parse it in js?
If not can u help me out with this JSON format itself?

Comment: No problems, I point out again, that this is not valid json, and that your table data is in fact, strings, not objects, fixing this in flask/pandas would be a new question. Fixing in JS would require something like: all_scores_Table = JSON.parse(this.state.scores.all_scores) which would give you something to look at in JS. Then you could use a loop very nearly identical to the one I gave you. My rule of thumb though is solve problems as far back in the architecture as you can, so it doesn't bite you again later.

Comment: Hi, have updated the format of the data, see if you can help me out now, have put the updated data in the question

Comment: `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: this.state.scores.map is not a function`, I'm getting this error although my output comes in form of an array, when I feed that manually it works but not when it directly comes from the API, although I have declared it as `scores: []`

Comment: I can't see your scores output, but I'm assuming it contains three *objects*. Map is an *Array* method. You'll want to build all tables separately, as they contain different elements. So as per my update to build an example table on all_scores, you'd want to use map on the scores.all_scores array, not the scores object.

Comment: I have been trying to send individual items as JSON for my testing purpose, so `scores` basically contains only `all_scores`, and output looks like an array, but not able to check the type. Is there a way I can convert it to array in React and then do `.map()`?

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help without seeing the returned JSON. My guess is that some inverted comma's have snuck in (as per your original json), and so you're trying to map a string, not an array.

Comment: The updated part in the question, where I have added the new JSON, is what I'm getting as an output right now and on using the map function in it I'm getting that error.