# Rendering change in component with new prop value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My react app is supposed to render various widgets using the value in the search bar. In theory, I search something, and the widgets display the data using a script corresponding to the search value. Currently, when I search something, the widgets do not re-render with the data corresponding to the new searched value.

Here is the code for a widget:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class SSIWidget extends  React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    }
    
    componentDidMount() {
        const script = document.createElement('script');
        script.src ="https://s3.tradingview.com/external-embedding/embed-widget-symbol-info.js";
        script.async = true;
        script.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(
        {
            "symbol": props.value,
            "width": 1000,
            "locale": "en",
            "colorTheme": "light",
            "isTransparent": false
        }
    )
    document.getElementById("myContainer6").appendChild(script); 
}

render() {
    
    return(
        <div id="myContainer6">
            <div className="tradingview-widget-container">
            <div className="tradingview-widget-container__widget">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
}
export default SSIWidget;
```

I tried to fix my issue with the following resources:

[How to pass data from one component to another component in onchange using React js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51999538/how-to-pass-data-from-one-component-to-another-component-in-onchange-using-react)

[Reactjs - passing state value from one component to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46426078/reactjs-passing-state-value-from-one-component-to-another)

I am passing an initialized search value for the widgets, which shows the data fine so I know I am passing the state correctly, but when I search a new value, it still shows the initial value data and not the new value data, bringing me to my hypothesis: the issue is probably because the script with the search value is only called when the component mounts, and not every time it renders.

How can I add the script in componentDidMount() to render() so that the widget re-renders every time the prop value changes?

Comment: You should use `componentDidUpdate` here, move your logic to  a separate function, call it in `componentDidMount` and call it when in `componentDidUpdate` when `prevProps.value !== this.props.value`

Comment: Have a look at this library it might be useful for you, [react-tradingview-widget](https://github.com/rafaelklaessen/react-tradingview-widget)

Comment: @Siddharth I am currently using that library for one of the widgets! It works perfectly, reflecting changes as the search bar is updated, because I embedded it in the component with the search bar. Several other widgets do not have easy libraries like that one, so I made separate components for each, and am asking about those

Comment: Okay, I hope your issue is fixed with `componentDidUpdate`. Also I noticied, in your componentDidMount you've written `props.value`, it should be `this.props.value`

Comment: @Siddharth I am trying to understand your solution. So, I create a new function, with all the script logic. I call this function in componentDidMount. But how do I keep track of the previous prop value? Create a new state value in the component and initialize it to the props value? and when the prev props value is not the same as current props, then call componentDidUpdate, and call the script function in componentDidUpdate?

Comment: You're not supposed to call `componentDidUpdate`, it's a component's lifecycle method and is called after every update. I've added a small snippet in the answer, that should help you out a bit :)

Comment: Thanks, will check it out and try! @Siddharth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `componentDidUpdate` here, move your logic to a separate function, call it in `componentDidMount` and call it in `componentDidUpdate` when `prevProps.value !== this.props.value`

From react docs:

> [componentDidUpdate()](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate) is invoked immediately after updating occurs. This method is not called for the initial render. Use this as an opportunity to operate on the DOM when the component has been updated. This is also a good place to do network requests as long as you compare the current props to previous props (e.g. a network request may not be necessary if the props have not changed).

```js
componentDidMount() {
    this.addWidget();
}

componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if(prevProps.value !== this.props.value) {
        this.addWidget();
    }
}


addWidget = () => {
    // add widget logic
}
```

Comment: Is PrevProps a state value?

Comment: As the name suggests they are the previous props, props before the update happened.
Let's say you pass 'abc' as the 'value' prop from parent, and then you update it to 'def'. So in this case, component will be re-rendered as the props got updated and your prevProps would be `{value: 'abc'}` and current props(this.props) would be `{value: 'def'}`